# Running Java Jar with included config via maven on flink yarn cluster

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, apache-flink, hadoop-yarn

I am using flink in a maven/java project and need to include my configs internally in the created jar.

So, I have added the following in my pom file. This includes all my yml configs (located in src/main/resources folder) in the jar, whose name I will pass as argument while executing.

```
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.yml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
                        <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>com.exmaple.MyApplication</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

The following main class code receives an arg based on which I decide what config to pick from resource, read(using snakeyaml) and use.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final ParameterTool parameterTool = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args);

    ClassLoader classLoader = MyApplication.class.getClassLoader();
    Yaml yaml = new Yaml();

    String filename = parameterTool.getRequired("configFilename");

    InputStream in  = classLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(filename);
    MyConfigClass = yaml.loadAs(in, MyConfigClass.class);

    ...

}
```

mvn clean install creates "my-shaded-jar.jar"

which I execute using command

```
java -jar /path/to/my-shaded-jar.jar --configFilename filename
```

It works on multiple systems, if I share the jar with others.

However I am facing issue, when I try to run the same jar in a yarn cluster on Hadoop, using the following command:-

```
HADOOP_CLASSPATH=`hadoop classpath` HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf ./flink-1.6.2/bin/flink run -m yarn-cluster -yd -yn 5 -ys 30 -yjm 10240 -ytm 10240 -yst -ynm some-job-name -yqu queue-name ./my-shaded-jar.jar --configFilename filename
```

I am getting following Error:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
 The program finished with the following exception:

org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error.
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:546)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:421)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.OptimizerPlanEnvironment.getOptimizedPlan(OptimizerPlanEnvironment.java:83)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgramUtils.createJobGraph(PackagedProgramUtils.java:78)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgramUtils.createJobGraph(PackagedProgramUtils.java:120)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.runProgram(CliFrontend.java:238)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:216)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:1053)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$11(CliFrontend.java:1129)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1754)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(HadoopSecurityContext.java:41)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1129)
Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.error.YAMLException: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.StreamReader.update(StreamReader.java:200)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.StreamReader.<init>(StreamReader.java:60)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.loadAs(Yaml.java:444)
    at com.example.MyApplication.main(MyApplication.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:529)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.io.PushbackInputStream.ensureOpen(PushbackInputStream.java:74)
    at java.io.PushbackInputStream.read(PushbackInputStream.java:166)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.UnicodeReader.init(UnicodeReader.java:90)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.UnicodeReader.read(UnicodeReader.java:122)
    at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:140)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.StreamReader.update(StreamReader.java:184)
```

Why does my solution works on any normal linux/mac systems, however the same jar with same args fails when running with flink run command on yarn cluster.
Is there a difference between how we generally execute jars and how yarn does it.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `classLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(filename)` with `classLoader.getResourceAsStream(filename)`.

1. `java.lang.ClassLoader#getSystemResourceAsStream` locates the resource through the system class loader, which is typically used to start the application.
2. `java.lang.ClassLoader#getResourceAsStream` will first search the parent class loader. That failing, it will invoke `findResource` of the current class loader.

To avoid dependency conflicts, classes in Flink applications are divided into two domains [1], which is also applied to Flink client, e.g. `CliFrontend`.

The **Java Classpath** includes the classes of Apache Flink and its core dependencies.
The **Dynamic User Code** includes the classes (and resources) of user jars.

So in order to find your "config file", which is packaged in your jar file, we should use the user code class loader (you can find the details of `userCodeClassLoader` in `org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram`), instead of the system classloader.

1. https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/debugging_classloading.html

Comment: Hi roban, what about changing `classLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(filename)` to `classLoader.getResourceAsStream(filename)`? It seems `getSystemResourceAsStream` uses system classloader.

Comment: Hi Victor, It works. Thanks a lot. Can you edit your initial answer and include why changing classloader.getSystemResourceAsStream to classloader.getResourceAsStream solves the issue.

Comment: Hi rohan, I have updated the answer.   And after debugging into the Flink source code, I think it's OK to use `MyApplication.class.getClassLoader`, since the main class is also loaded with user code class loader. Can you give it a try to verify this?

Comment: Yes, it is ok to use "MyApplication.class.getClassLoader". 
Nice udpate. Accepted and upvoted. Thanks.